# Calculus AB: Finding Volume when Revolving a Graph (Possibly Washer Method?)

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

Find the volume of the enclosed shape of graphs $y=x^3$ and $y=x$ when revolved around the $x$-axis.

I attempted to solve this using the integral from $[0, 1]$ and squaring the first function and subtracting it from the second function, also squared, to get the volume. Is this correct?

My answer is $\frac{4\pi}{21}$.

Comment: Did  you sketch the scenario?

Comment: I used Desmos Graphing Tool but I do not how or am unable to link the graph. The graphs meet at x=0 and x=1 in the given interval.

Comment: Yeah, it looks good. I really recommend making the sketch by hand of the inner and outer radius for more complicated problems of this nature, though. It'll make life easier in the long run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $x$ is greater than $x^3$ in the interval $[0,1]$. Try sketching the "washer". Then volume of each washer will be $dV=\pi r_o^2dx-\pi r_i^2dx$ where $r_o,r_i$ are the outer and inner radii respectively.

[image: sketch of y=x, y=x^3 rotated about x-axis, washer method]

Upon identifying $x$ as the outer radius and $x^3$ as the inner, you can integrate. Your answer is correct.

$$\pi\int_0^1 x^2-x^6 dx = \frac{4\pi}{21}$$

Useful checks:

Is the volume positive? Yes.

Is the volume less than a cylinder of height $1$ and radius $1$ (why did I choose this?). That is, is the volume less than $\pi$? Yes.

Then our answer is reasonable.